# вывод комментариев на vue js

Tags: vue.js

```
    comments: [
        {id: 1, userName: 'Piter', text: 'some text1', parent: null},
        {id: 2, userName: 'Aivn', text: 'some text1', parent: [
                {id: 1, userName: 'Piter', text: 'some text2', parent: null},
                {id: 2, userName: 'Piter', text: 'some text2', parent: null},
                {id: 3, userName: 'Piter', text: 'some text2', parent: [
                    {id: 1, userName: 'Piter', text: 'some text3', parent: null},
                    {id: 2, userName: 'Piter', text: 'some text3', parent: null}
                ] }]
        },
        {id: 3, userName: 'Aivn', text: 'some text1', parent: 3},
    ]
```

Прилетает такой массив из объектов, вложенный, как вывести его вложенные parent,ы ??? v-for переберет только первую вложенность

Comment: А в чем проблема создать [рекурсивный компонент](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B)?

Comment: Вот если б я только знал как это делать)) Но в принципе нашел Element тег el-tree

Comment: Посмотри [ссылку на документацию](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B)